# Finding the number of ways a list of numbers has the same sum, but different numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question my professor gave me (paraphrased):
“An employee is tasked with matching a purchase order to the correct shipping container. To reduce his work, the employee simply checks if the total price of the purchase order, and the price on the shipping container match and if the number of distinct items on both orders match. The store has 'x' units each of 'n' distinct items, and customers can order any combination of these. The individual price for the rth distinct item is given by P(r)=A+(r-1)${A\over 2}$, where 'A' is a constant≠0. For orders with 'r' distinct items, where r≤n, what is the interval in which the error rate of the employee lies?”

I wrote down some basic stuff to help myself out:

$\displaystyle \Sigma_{i=1}^r$ x<sub>i</sub>P(r<sub>i</sub>) gives the total price of an order where x<sub>i</sub> is the quantity of product anywhere from 1 to 'x'.

The total possible number of orders for exactly 'r' distinct items is x<sup>r</sup>$n\choose r$

Since the individual prices are in a progression, P(u+v)+P(u-v)=2P(u) where 'u' and 'v' are positive integers such that (u+v) and (u-v) $\in$ [1,r].

To find two sums that are equal but with differing individual quantities or items, let us assume a principal order (x<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>r</sub>r<sub>r</sub>). For the same number of terms and equal price, if x<sub>i</sub>r<sub>i</sub> is increased by some quantity 'm' such than m+x<sub>i</sub>≤x, then r<sub>j</sub> (i<j≤r) must be decreased by some quantity 'l' (l<m<x) or r<sub>h</sub> (h<i) must be decreased by some quantity 'p' (m<p). This should hold true even if the increased (deviated from the principal order) replaces more than one distinct item.

For r=1, the error rate E(1) can be found as such:

For an error, x<sub>1</sub>P(r<sub>1</sub>)=x<sub>2</sub>P(r<sub>2</sub>)
Here,let r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> give any two arbitrary and distinct items. So,

0=(x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)(A)+(${A\over 2}$)(x<sub>2</sub>(p-1)-x<sub>1</sub>(q-1))
and,

X<sub>1</sub>/x<sub>2</sub>=${(2A+A(c-1))\over (2A+A(d-1))}$ where r<sub>2</sub> is taken to be the 'c'th item and r<sub>1</sub> is taken to be the 'd'th item. Using this ratio in the initial equation, we finally get,

c$^2$-3d$^2$+2c-2d+2cd=0 where c,d have to be integers and $\in$ [1,r]. An error pair arises when c≠d. The pairs $\notin$ error pairs, arise when c=d. There are 'x' such pairs for each distinct item. That is, there are 'nx' no-error pairs for r=1. So, E(1)≤1-(${nx\over(x^r)*n}$) since there are some 'excluded middle' pairs when the prices of the order and container simply don't match which will decrease the error rate somewhat, (and when the number of distinct items is different.)

Even for r=1, the situation seems somewhat complex.

Clearly, E(r)$\in$(0,1) is a trivial solution. I note, however, that the error rate can never be 1, since there will always exist at least 1 case where the orders match up correctly. The error rate should also never be 0 except for conditions like r=0, since even at r=1, the error rate is quite high.

I then considered the error rate E(r) at n=1 where customers can only buy 1 of each item. However, it quickly became evident that r elements of an arithmetic progression can give equal sums readily. I assumed again a principal order, which would enable me to calculate the number of cases via the number of possible integer deviations that yielded the same sum. The problem now became that I had to choose r elements from n total items, which complicated matters.

How would you approach this problem?